# Open SharePoint Library file directly through hyperlink

Tags: sharepoint-online, hyperlink, sharepoint-library

I need to open the first pdf file in a library through a hyperlink on my homepage. Currently I have set the URL to the Library view so that the end user can see the file in library and open it, however I need to open the first file directly rather then going to library and clicking it.

In the library there will be multiple files, I have created a view to get only the last uploaded file.

Now how do I get the URL for the file to open directly since the file name can change.

Working on Sharepoint online

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can only get the link for a specific document. Real-time refreshing for a hyperlink would not be possible in SharePoint Online.

If you can create a library view to show only the last uploaded file, you can use the document library web part on modern pages (or list web part in classic page) and select the specific view. You will be able to open the file directly from the web part.

Reference:
[Use the Document Library web part.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-document-library-web-part-a9dfecc3-2050-4528-9f00-2c5afc5731b0)